# Overlaying functions on top of each other. Chrome trace

Tags: json, google-chrome, trace

In this json I need to show some instructions which started while some else instructions with the same name are executed, but in google trace i can see this. Fow can i fix it if I can`t change tid?

JSON file is given below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jupxK.png)

```
        {
        "ph": "X",
        "cat": "cpu_op",
        "name": "aten::empty",
        "pid": 694985,
        "tid": 694985,
        "ts": 1666382282442255,
        "dur": 21000,
        "args": {
            "Trace name": "PyTorch Profiler",
            "Trace iteration": 1,
            "External id": 14
        }
    },
    {
        "ph": "X",
        "cat": "cpu_op",
        "name": "aten::empty",
        "pid": 694985,
        "tid": 694985,
        "ts": 1666382282442355,
        "dur": 21000,
        "args": {
            "Trace name": "PyTorch Profiler",
            "Trace iteration": 2,
            "External id": 13
        }
    }
```